# Icon source graphics?

Tags: icon

I need to create a "document" icon for an application on the mac, and I need a source "blank page" image to use for it. Is Apple OK with using their own blank page icon as the backing for your icon? If not, is there a free equivalent somewhere I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple encourages you to use the system standard images that ship as part of Xcode.

You can see this clearly in section 2.E. of the [Xcode 4.2 License agreement](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf).

> E. Use of System Provided Images. The system provided images, as
>   defined in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines for the Mac OS and the
>   iPhone OS, that are created and owned by Apple ("System Provided
>   Images") are licensed to you solely for the purpose of developing Mac
>   and iPhone applications respectively using the Developer Software.

I am not a lawyer, and there are further restrictions, but it is good form to stick with the provided templates unless you have a good reason and the time/skills/money to invent your own.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I finally found the standard icons in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle to use.

Comment: I've never heard of people getting into trouble using those icons, but do note they are distributed under the Mac OS X license and are not part of Xcode or the license I posted above.

Comment: Does Xcode include versions of those? I'd love to use them if they exist, but I couldn't find them anywhere. :(